# Flexboxで、「.left { flex: 1 100px; } 」　は、「.left { flex: 0 0 100px; 」？

Tags: css

```
.left{ flex: 0 100px; }
.right{ flex: 0 100px; }
.center { flex: 1; }
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

を

```
.left {
  flex: 100px;
  background: tomato;
}
.right {
  flex: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.center {
  flex: 1;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

と書くと、
下の画像のように、
左右の100pxが効かなくなります。

省略されるのが、**flex-grow**になっているみたいです！

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

デフォルトでは

**flex-grow:0

flex-shrink:1

flex-basis:auto**
のはずですから、
上の場合、

```
.left{ flex: 0 1 100px; }
.right{ flex: 0 1 100px; }
.left{ flex: 1 1 auto; }
```

となっているかとおもいきや、
これとは違う結果となります。
どうも下のようになっているようです。

```
.left {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: tomato;
}
.right {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.center {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

3つとも
**flex-shrinkが0**になっているようです！

```
.left{ flex: 1 100px; }
```

と書いた時、
省略されるのはどのプロパティですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/#propdef-flex によると、flexの構文は以下のようになっています。

```
none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’>? || <‘flex-basis’> ]
```

それを踏まえて、上記の

```
.left{ flex: 1 100px; }
```

を考えると、省略されるのは `flex-shrink` となります。
また、上記のW3Cの定義によると、

> <‘flex-grow’>
>   When omitted, it is set to 1.
>   <‘flex-shrink’>
>   When omitted, it is set to 1.
>   <‘flex-basis’>
>   When omitted from the flex shorthand, its specified value is 0.

とあり、それぞれ省略されたときの値は `1 1 0` となっているようです。
したがって、

```
.left {
  flex: 100px;
  background: tomato;
}
.right {
  flex: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.center {
  flex: 1;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

を略記せずに書くと、

```
.left {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  background: tomato;
}
.right {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.center {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

となるかと思います。
flexboxについてあまり詳しくなかったので試してみたところ、見た目は同じようになるようですね。

```css
*{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox>.left {
  flex: 100px;
  background: tomato;
}

.flexbox>.center {
  flex: 1;
  background: skyblue;
}

.flexbox>.right {
  flex: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.flexbox2 {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox2>.left {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  background: tomato;
}

.flexbox2>.center {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background: skyblue;
}

.flexbox2>.right {
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="flexbox2">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます！W3Cの上のページでは、表の部分のInitialがそれぞれ「flex-grow：0、flex-shrink： 1、flex-basis： auto」と書かれていますので、初期値と省略された時の値は異なるということのようですね。なかなか分かりにくですね。

Comment: よく見てみたら表の中は`1 0 auto`になっていますね。
draft版では`0 1 auto`に修正されているようなので単なる誤表記かと思ったら、意外と深い議論がなされていました。初期値と省略されたときの値が〜〜のところにも関わってきそうな話題だったので、参考までに。
https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/223

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます。